# Dialogflow CX - How to make an API Call to a specific Flow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

How can I make a Google Dialogflow REST API call to a specific flow? I basically want to query an intent detection for a different flow other than the "Default Start Flow".

For example I can use this link to make an API call:

`https://{endpoint}/v3/{session=projects/*/locations/*/agents/*/sessions/*}:detectIntent`

Except it will use the Default Start Flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that it does not make sense to do this, what we should be doing instead is creating a route from the "Default Start Flow" to the other Flow

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Dialogflow CX request documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/QueryParameters) you can specify a "currentPage" parameter. Dialogflow will start intent recognition from that page instead of the "Default Start Flow". This allows you to directly jump into a specific entry point of another flow.

*Note:* previous state, **including parameters**, will be ignored. So if parameters have already been set, they should be passed along as well.